# How do i execute a stored procedure in wcf module c#

Tags: c#, wcf

I am creating a wcf module that i would like to execute a stored procedure and return the results. This is what i have so far

```
public static class Provder
{

 private const string CommandSchema_FullName = "Table3";
    public static IEnumerable<ProviderModel> Get(Func<ProviderModel> )
    {
        var query = new StringBuilder();
        query.AppendFormat("SELECT * FROM {0}", CommandSchema_FullName);
        if (criteria != null)
            return ExecuteQuery(query.ToString()).Where(criteria).ToArray();
        return ExecuteQuery(query.ToString());
```

//i can read from a table like above,im not sure how to add in a new stored procedure that i would like to call
        }

```
    private static IEnumerable<ProviderModel> ExecuteQuery(string query)
    {
        var result = new List<ProviderModel>();
        using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["netTiersConnectionString"].ToString()))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            var reader = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection).ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                result.Add(new ProviderModel
                {

                });
            }
            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
        return result;
    }
    private static bool ExecuteCommand(string command)
    {
        var result = false;
        using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["netTiersConnectionString"].ToString()))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            try
            {
                var recordsAffected = new SqlCommand(command, sqlConnection).ExecuteNonQuery();
                result = true;
            }
            catch (SqlException)
            {
                result = false;
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlConnection.Close();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
public class ProviderModel
{

}
```

This is the stored procedure i want to call in the above methods

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE GetListCodes 
AS
BEGIN
    select concat(p.CourseName,s.LeagueTitle,' ',p.Abbreviation) As Result,p.ProgramCode
  FROM Table1 p inner join Table2 s on p.Code=s.Code
END
GO
```

I am not sure how to call the sp GetListCodes in the above wcf model. I dont have any parameters to pass,i would just like to execute the stored procedure and get the results.

Comment: I am not sure what the question is, are you trying to write a wcf service and call the stored proc in the service?

Comment: @mahlatse yes, im not sure how to call the sp

Comment: Can you show part of the service implementation?

Comment: @mahlatse i just updated the code to show how i can read from a table in the data base. im not sure about the sp tho

Answer (score 0):

What you need to exceute a store procedure, on the command is a simple line

> cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

In your case, you would have to replace the line

> var recordsAffected = new SqlCommand(command,
>   sqlConnection).ExecuteNonQuery();

with

```
var cmd= new SqlCommand(command, sqlConnection);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
var recordsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

There is a nice little tutorial you can find at https://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson07

And Miscrosoft also has an article located at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/executing-a-command